# Dump SQL query in Twig template

Tags: templating, mysql

Is possible to dump a query made on a twig template for a statement like this one for example:

`craft.entries.section('homepage')`

Can we some how see the actual SQL query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see each SQL query that is run for a page by turning [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) on and opening your console to read the 'Profiling Summary Report'.

You can see a total query count and each query beings with `system.db.CDbCommand.query`.

I'd advise maybe isolating the twig code on its own template to avoid having to work out which query was a result of the twig code you're after.

Comment: You can also try to filter the rows returned to the console to find the right one. In this example using "homepage" as a search term.

Comment: Yeah this actually what i did, i isolated the twig code but instead of looking at the 'Profiling Summary Report' i used a plugin named `Query log`.The  'Profiling Summary Report' is much easier cause no extra plugin is needed.

Answer (score 6):

In Craft 3 you can use `getRawSql()` at the end of the element query.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('blog').getRawSql() %}

{{ entries }}
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much! Very useful for debugging twig api templates.